# load external css file in body tag

Tags: html, css

usually, external css file loading code is put on header of html.

```
<head>

...
<link href="/uploadify/uploadify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
...

</head>
```

but, sometime I should put my css loading code in body tag,
I mean..

```
<body>
...
<link href="/uploadify/uploadify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
</body>
```

so my question is,
is it okay to put my css loading code in body tag?

Comment: It's not valid HTML; it usually works, but it's not a good practice. (See the dupe for more in-depth info)

Comment: To validate HTML, when inside body tag, change this:
`<link href="/uploadify/uploadify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`
To this:
`<style type="text/css">
  @import url("/uploadify/uploadify.css");
</style>`

Comment: @LeopoldoSanczyk - Apparently, no, "style" inside "body" is not valid.

Answer (score -4):

No, it is not okay to put a `link` element in the body tag. See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-LINK) (links to the HTML4.01 specs, but I believe it is true for all versions of HTML):

> “This element defines a link. Unlike `A`, it may only appear in the `HEAD` section of a document, although it may appear any number of times.”

Comment: In HTML5 it's totally OK to put a `<link>` or `<style>` in `<body>`. In fact, you can even have scoped `<style>`s that apply only to a part of your document!

Comment: @Vilx - Curious: Can you provide a link to where the spec says it's OK?

Comment: @Vilx-, Scoped style has virtually no browser support at the moment.  Hopefully that changes in a few years!  http://caniuse.com/#search=scope

Comment: @Vilx- In HTML5, `link` can only be used within the body if it uses the `itemprop` attribute instead of `rel`. [Spec Reference](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#the-link-element)

Comment: the direct quote: `If the rel attribute is used, the element is restricted to the head element. When used with the itemprop attribute, the element can be used both in the head element and in the body of the page, subject to the constraints of the microdata model.`

Comment: @sri, How do we use the itemprop to load a CSS file?

Comment: @Pacerier, check answer of this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236097/is-link-not-rel-stylesheet-allowed-to-be-used-in-body)

Comment: @Vilx- your comment about scoped css got me very excited! However it is only supported by one browser. :( http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp

Comment: @Will - Yes, there is that. :( On the other hand, all browsers currently support putting `<style>` anywhere in the document. Although it won't be scoped and it won't validate, it'll still work. So - it's something...

Comment: The body-ok keywords defined by this specification are prefetch, and stylesheet.

Comment: @sri @Ravi Dhoriya The current specs make no mention of `itemprop` - just that the elements in rel must be 'body-ok'.

Comment: I'm going to put link elements in the body now, if only to piss off the standards zealots.

Comment: @sri `itemprop` is not working for me today. But `rel` is doing the job.

Comment: @Pacerier you can use `<link rel="stylesheet" />` directly in `<body>` tag, cuz the `stylesheet` type is `body-ok`. you can read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#targetText=A%20element%20can%20occur,is%20permitted%20in%20the%20body. or https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#body-ok

Comment: @Vilx- Your comment should be an answer to the question. I would vote for it!

Comment: @SriKadimisetty Wrong. The spec specifies that it is allowed, even when you use the `rel` attribute: "_If a link element has an itemprop attribute, or **has a rel attribute that contains only keywords that are body-ok**, then the element is said to be allowed in the body._" => So, it's even allowed when the `rel` attribute contains only keywords that are body-ok. Allowed attributes are listed [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#body-ok): "_The body-ok keywords are dns-prefetch, modulepreload, pingback, preconnect, prefetch, preload, prerender, and **stylesheet**._"

Comment: @MartinBraun Spec changed. As I apparently linked to a living doc instead of a static one. Diffing the current spec with this part of quote in  Christopf's comment made at the time should attest that it was true then — “If the rel attribute is used, the element is restricted to the head element … ”. As of today the spec (updated Jan 12  '21) reads “If the rel attribute is used, the element can only sometimes be used in the body of the page …” I should have tracked down and used a static link back then.

Comment: @SriKadimisetty Alright then, I thought it is static. Thanks for clearing this up. So to sum things up: It's allowed to put a `link` element in the `body` with `rel="stylesheet"`. The question is just: Will it remain this way?