# css validator error HTML5 Conformance Checker

Tags: css

Error Line 22, Column 63: Element link is missing required attribute property.

link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css"

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Check if [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549726/element-link-is-missing-required-attribute-property) helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your link element to the `<head>` section of your HTML document.

Comment: Its already in the <head> section
http://m-and-m.in/demo/abharan/main.html
http://validator.w3.org/
Errors found while checking this document as HTML5!
55 Errors, 12 warning(s)

Comment: @user2362327 — That page does not exhibit that error.