# Vuejs SPA need to load css for ltr and rtl based on language

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, right-to-left, vue-router

I'm building a website using Vue but I have 2 separate css files, 1 for normal ltr and one for rtl.

Now according to the URL xyz.com/en or xyz.com/ar I can serve the appropriate file, based on server-side logic. However, I want this to be done on the client via Vue Router.

So that the URLs can look like this xyz.com/#/en or xyz.com/#/ar

Answer (score 0):

You could have language specific CSS inclusions `<link href="..." />` from the respective components for EN and AR as shown below.

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/en',
      name: 'Welcome EN...',
      component: WelcomeEN
    },
    {
      path: '/ar',
      name: 'Welcome AR...',
      component: WelcomeAR
    }
  ]
```

Do you think that would work for you ?

Comment: Isn't the <link> tag supposed to be in the <head> section of the document?

Comment: Interesting :) I found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957446/load-external-css-file-in-body-tag, will try and see and mark as accepted if it works smoothly

Comment: Well, technically it does work but it's not the recommended practice... So I would not like to use this technique for a public facing website...

Comment: So this worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/30308194/136999, just need to see if it can be validated by an HTML 5 validator

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of conditional css loading inside a component

```
// change x to change color
const x = true;
if(x)
   require("./assets/style.css");
else
   require("./assets/stylegreen.css");
```

[code snippet of conditional css loading in vue](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-v54wd)