# The fastest loading of fancyBox/jQuery v3 without loosing scores in Google PageSpeed Insights

Tags: jquery, fancybox, pagespeed, fancybox-3

Currently we have fancyBox v2.1.5 and jQuery v1.11.3 in one of our old web projects. They are attached to the HTML pages right before the closing `</body>` tag like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            beforeShow: function () {
                var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');
                this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);
                this.title = alt;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
```

The fancyBox's CSS is added like this in the `<head>` section:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

When I launch Google's PageSpeed Insights test for our HTML pages, Google always mentions this CSS and tells us that we have 1 blocking CSS resource in above-the-fold content. To solve this problem and to make the load time of pages even better, I am going to upgrade to the latest versions of fancyBox and jQuery (which will also bring new features).

The [home page](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) of the fancyBox project tells us how to add the v3 to HTML pages:

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

If I add these lines before the closing `</body>` tag, will it help to achieve my goal? Are there any other tips how we can speed up loading of our pages when using fancyBox/jQuery (say, by adding the `async` attribute in the `<script>` tag or hosting fancyBox/jQuery files on our webserver)?

P.S. One possible problem with the suggested solution is that the `<link>` tag should be placed only in the `<head>` section, though it seems it works in body too in HTML5 (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957446/load-external-css-file-in-body-tag)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Google recommendations - https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery and this SO thread - [How to load CSS Asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759272/how-to-load-css-asynchronously)

Comment: After experimenting with available approaches, I decided to load fancyBox's CSS in the page body with `<script>var newStyle = document.createElement('link'); newStyle.href = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css'; newStyle.rel = 'stylesheet'; newStyle.type = 'text/css'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newStyle);</script>`. Are there any drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: Since this CSS is not (most likely) critical, it would be best to load in the next frame to prioritize painting visible content (there is an example in the first link), but this would be fine, too.

Comment: don't you think that deferred loading of fancyBox's CSS using the code snippet from the Optimize CSS Delivery article may lead to improper functioning of fancyBox? What if the fancyBox developers thought that their CSS would be loaded the normal way as they showed on the home page? What about an additional paint cycle for the page after loading the CSS (flickering or something like that)?

Comment: As the author of fancybox, I can assure you that this is not that important.