# How to load CSS filed inside the body in JSP?

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I'm learning JSP these days, and really want to place some css files to the head during the body sequence. But I can't figure out on Java codings.

> If you want to load it in the middle of the page, you can use a javascript function that does the same as the first paragraph here, except it deletes the object that appears in the body, and appends it to the head object. I do that if I use ajax to update a page. [external css in body of html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311569/external-css-in-body-of-html-file)

I saw this answer on other question, and I'm curious how to do it?  Also I found it on how to do it on Jquery, but is there anyway on "JAVA way"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Do you mean you want to include CSS files, so the stylings can be used in the body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSP is really just HTML by the time it reaches the browser.  CSS should be imported in the `head` element of the HTML document, not the `body`.  CSS can be defined 'on the run' in the `style` attribute of an element of the body, but that is harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare css file in your jsp head tag likes this;

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"></link>
```

and you can use this in your jsp page.

Comment: Everyone knows that and Yes I know! But, in some skin folders at User side interface, the only way to add the css is in the body for some skins. Sigh :(

Comment: @user1589063 Do you want to create themes for jsp pages?