# Add css file to only a single page (ASP.NET master pages)

Tags: asp.net

How can I add a css file to only a child page while using ASP.NET master pages rather then specifying them in the master?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify it in child page inside the content as mentioned below

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<link href="Css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

scope of this css will remain for this page only

Comment: references to css and js files should all be in the <head> section so they're loaded before the body is. Adrian Iftode's way is more w3c-compliant and more efficient.

Answer (score 14):

In the master page

```
<head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

In the specific page

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
  <link href="~/pagecssfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: this one is actually a lot better since the <link> tag must be in the <head> part, for quick-rendering and w3c-compatibility reasons. Read more here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642212/whats-the-difference-if-i-put-css-file-inside-head-or-body

Comment: this is a really neat solution, +1