# Style (h and p) tags inside div. Only access inside <body>

Tags: html, css, styles

I need to style h1, h2, h3... and p tags inside a div but I only have access to the content area.

If it where possible, this would be what I'd use:

```
<div style="h1{padding:0;}p{font-size:1.4em;color:#000}">
```

Is there a solution to do this ? Apart from adding the style to every element.

Thanks

Comment: does the div have an `id` or a `class`?

Comment: @jmore009 — That wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Quentin Maybe I'm assuming, but  `Only access inside <body>` to me means on the HTML side...what about the CSS side? He could easily target a div if there is some identifier and access to css

Comment: I have full access to the div (otherwise I could add one) but "ONLY" access to the body; not to external files either.

Answer (score 2):

Although HTML syntax restricts `style` elements to the `head` part, this requirement is not enforced in practice. It works inside `body`, too. You just need to take into account that the effects are global to the document. Thus, to limit the effect to elements inside a certain element, you need to use suitable selectors. Example (I have added a color setting because the effect of just `padding: 0` as in the question in not noticeable: it equals the default):

```html
<h1>Heading outside the div</h1>
<p>A paragraph outside the div.</p>
<div class=mydiv>
<style>
.mydiv h1 { padding: 0; color: green; }
.mydiv p { font-size: 1.4em; color: #000; }
</style>
<h1>Heading inside the div</h1>
<p>A paragraph inside the div.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I did think of this one and started checking out arguments of why not to use it. Like this one, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1642259/3319002 from Mauris. And I'd be scr*w*d if new browsers would stop allowing this; for this, or some other, reason. Thank you for the suggestion, I might still use it. For now, I "solved it" by manually adding the styles to every element :(

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good solution.

Style elements may only appear in the head.

Inline style only applies to the element the attribute appears on.

The closest you can come is to use JavaScript to dynamically modify the stylesheet.

You would be better fixing whatever problem is preventing you from modifying the head section.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid unwanted changes inside divs i will be using to divs with 2 unique id's:red and green

If you want different style for specific divs:

```
<div id="red"><h1>red</h1><p>red</p>
<div id="green"><h1>green</h1><p>green</p>

body #red > h1,body #red >p{
color:red;

}
body #green > h1,body #green > p{
color:green;

}
```

Comment: People need to take accountability for their downvotes. Not only so the person who posted knows, but for future viewers that come across this and may not know why it's incorrect.

I didn't downvote but I will attempt to explain the issue on behalf of the anonymous downvoter: OP does not have access to anything but the `body` therefore he can not add css to target the `div`. Also targeting a generic `div` inside is not generally a good idea as it could lead to other `p`, `h2`, etc. tags recieving unwarranted styles

Comment: Thank you @jmore009,As for general divs this is why i added #green and #red