# Add CSS to one page only with Ionic 2

Tags: css, ionic2

I know that in `Ionic 2` I can write style code in page-specific SCSS files in `/app/pages/page-name/page-name.scss`, and then include links to these in `/app/theme/app.core.scss`. However, this way the page-specific style codes go into the complete app style file, increasing it's size even for pages that many users might never access.

How can I create style code (either inside it's own CSS/SCSS file, or inside a style block in the rendered page) that is only included in one specific page? Is this even recommended in `Ionic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not recommended in Ionic and I don't really understand what's the benefit of doing that, because the styles are then *minified*, so the size of the final style file won't be reduced *that* much (and you will have to modify a lot of things to **try** to make it work that way).

Even though, you could modify your `gulpfile.js` in order to change the way it works by default (minifying and putting all your styles together in one file) in order to make each `scss` file (belonging to a single page) to be compiled in a single `css` file per page (located in a `www/styles` folder) and then importing them in each `ionic page's html` with

`<link md-href="styles/pageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">`

you will have to import those styles in the `body` of the `html page` (because Ionic app gets loaded inside `<ion-app></ion-app>` which is inside the `body` of the `index.html` page).

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642212/whats-the-difference-if-i-put-css-file-inside-head-or-body) that works in all modern browsers, but I'm sure that's not the recommended way to work with `Ionic`, and I don't think it worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

See angular2 documentation, not sure it will work with the url templates without modifying the gulpfile but this should get you started
=> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#using-component-styles

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Tour of Heroes</h1>
    <hero-app-main [hero]=hero></hero-app-main>`,
  styles: ['h1 { font-weight: normal; }'],
  directives: [HeroAppMainComponent]
})
```

or a specific url

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-details',
  template: `
    <h2>{{hero.name}}</h2>
    <hero-team [hero]=hero></hero-team>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['app/hero-details.component.css'],
  directives: [HeroTeamComponent]
})
```