# Why does "iframe.hidden{display:none}" appear under the navbar when the site is viewed on a mobile device?

Tags: html, iframe, tumblr-themes

I'm making a site with Tumblr. The code iframe.hidden{display:none} shows on the top left when I look at the site from my phone. I can't find iframe.hidden{display:none} anywhere in my code. Is it because of how Tumblr renders code or possibly on their end?
Below is an image of what I'm talking about.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX9ek.png)

Comment: i'm not familiar with tumblr, does it have plugins you add, or can you download your site to a desktop enviroment?

if you can you should be able to find a search and replace plugin or program fairly easily and type the code appearing on your site in there and it'll tell you where the error is

it looks like something is missing so your browser is reading it as text

i see you've been downvoted, i'd suggest posting an actual link to your site next time as there isn't much we can do with a screen shot

Comment: What about uploading the code you wrote to help you out?

Comment: an elaborate description of your problem is advised to help you on stack overflow. Please mention all details with suitable code. And yes, also tell what you have done to solve this and has it worked or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that your web page is not coded correctly. When I opened, https://raffalaw.tumblr.com/.

See below just under body tag :

[image: Inspecting your Web page]

You have put different `<link>`, styling in `<body>` tag. It's not recommended to put `styling` and `<link>` tags in `<body>` tags. See : [What's the difference if I put css file inside <head> or <body>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642212/whats-the-difference-if-i-put-css-file-inside-head-or-body).

Obviously, its breaking somewhere in your actual code. I would appreciate if you can show snippets of your actual code.

Comment: That was not a helpful answer at all.

Comment: @DustinSnider The nature of Trenton Erker's problem suggests that he's missing any bracket, character, etc. which is making his code break. This issue can be checked by using developer tools in Browser. If he opens mobile view in Desktop browser and inspect that line then he can reach to the line that is causing problem. And if you read his his question carefully, he asks "Any ideas what might cause this and how to fix it?". So I am just giving ideas. Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: You basically said "I there is a problem somewhere, caused by something. Check to see what it is." That's not being helpful, obviously he know's there is a problem or he wouldn't of posted here.

Comment: So then you update your answer when I tell you how terrible your answer was to include mine. Class act.

Comment: @DustinSnider, I read the question,  your answer and even all your comments. I think you are not at all interested in understanding the nature of his problem and seems that you want to show something good with your answer. Just look at the damn problem, it's totally rubbish. It should be immediately downvoted because it it is unclear, doesn't show any pre work to solve it and many other points. If any moderator comes to this question, even by chance, he would simply remove it because it doesn't fit with the stack overflow question criterion.

Comment: I am not a coward. You think I have included your answer. First of all, Why would I include someone's answer which is actually not helping anyone. I don't what kind of simulator you have used for this webpage testing, but it's all of no use. Again, I have already told him in my previous answer that to look in inspect element, and you will find the problem's solution. That was it. Why should I even bother to open someone else's URL when he himself is not showing support by giving code snippets. You thought very cleverly as a opportunity to help him out all the way through.

Comment: Stack overflow is not for spoon feeding. Let people do their work on their own, and we'll just guide them. So, I thought I should atleast give a thought of opening a URL for once, and as I opened it, I saw an immensely bad coding structure which can easily lead to problems (in this case it has lead to one). So, I clearly mentioned in my answer that you have bad coding structure, including tags in wrong places. And my suggestion to him has always remained the same, that your code is breaking somewhere, it's mistyped. This suggestion has no reference to your presence, not even to your answer.

Comment: I don't disagree its not of particular great quality of a question, my issue is you came to the question left an even worse answer to the question than the question was, the first answer you gave had absolute no value, it wasn't even worth anyone's time to read. I called you out on giving no help, then assisted him and linked him to tools he can use in the future to figure it out for himself and tried to explain a little bit of what might of caused it and where to look. Then you came back basically copied my answer and updated yours.

Comment: Its sad really, you provide a useless answer. Then when someone helps them out a little more, links them to a tool to use in the future, and gives them a lead on where to look for the issue you come back through and update your terrible answer to include the details from mine. Then you talk about how this question shouldn't of even been asked on StackOverflow, that might be true and you should of just said that to begin with and moved on. It sad really, your need to try to inflate your rep score so bad.

Comment: @rohankvashisht I have rephrased the question. Thanks for pointing out that a moderator would disapprove. Is it now qualified as an appropriate question/formatted correctly?

Comment: @rohankvashisht I don't know why it looks like in developer. I have only one <body> and these are the first few lines: <body> <!-- Navbar --> <div class="w3-top"> <ul class="w3-navbar w3-black w3-card-2 w3-left-align" style="color:white;"> <li class="w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-opennav w3-right"> <a class="w3-padding-large" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a> </li>

Comment: @Trenton Erker, your question is still lacking signs of research, you should mention in the question that what have you tried to solve it ? How far has it worked for you. Anyways, as you are saying in above comment, make it more possible that css rendering through backend language is creating problem. I don't know which language does Tumblr uses. There might be a problem in any add-on, plugin of Tumblr. Try to work out with using alternative plugins. Because, I see the problem arises from backend code and I think Tumblr won't let you touch that.

Answer (score 0):

So I went ahead and pulled up your website in a mobile device simulator over at http://testobject.com/ which you can do as well for free. I then opened up the dev tools for the browser and saw directly under the body tag for you webpage is the following line

```
figure{margin:0}.tmblr-iframe{position:absolute}.tmblr-iframe.hide{display:none}
```

I am not a big tumblr user, almost don't use it at all but my guess based on looking in the head section is wherever you paste in custom css this line of css is not typed correctly, which is causing it not to be picked up as css and instead displayed as plain text. I would start by looking there, hope this helps.

Comment: Also you would see the rest of the text in the line I posted if the nav bar wasn't covering up everything except the "iframe.hide{display:none}".

Comment: The way Tumlbr render's its CSS is not very nicely, I could be wrong but take a look at the .w3-progress-container line in your CSS it might be missing a closing }

Comment: Trenton Erker, I hope you select my answer when you do get a chance to review this, as @rohankvashisht basically took my answer after I called him out on how terrible his first answer was. I am happy to help if you need more help.

Comment: Ha, thanks man. I checked the .w3-progress-container and it is closed.

Comment: These are the first few lines under the body tag: <body>
<!-- Navbar -->
<div class="w3-top">
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-black w3-card-2 w3-left-align" style="color:white;">
  <li class="w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-opennav w3-right">
    <a class="w3-padding-large" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  </li>

Comment: Okay, is there anyway you can post a copy of your <head> section to something like JSFiddle?

Comment: If you are not looking for further help, I would ask you to please select an answer.

Comment: I found the answer. It was a missing bracket in the head on a meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that there was a meta tag in the head not closed. I added the bracket at the end and the mysterious code disappeared.
https://trentonerker.tumblr.com/post/155377765774/how-to-fix